# как отправить json на сервер fetch javascript? Все говорят только о том, как получить json

Tags: javascript

```
fetch('url', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: 'foo=bar'
}).then(function(response) {
    // Стоит проверить код ответа.
    if (!response.ok) {
        // Сервер вернул код ответа за границами диапазона [200, 299]
        return Promise.reject(new Error(
            'Response failed: ' + response.status + ' (' + response.statusText + ')'
        ));
    }

    // Далее будем использовать только JSON из тела ответа.
    return response.json();
}).then(function(data) {
    // ... Делаем что-то с данными.
}).catch(function(error) {
    // ... Обрабатываем ошибки.
});
```

Comment: ну так и кладите в `body` json строку

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, стрингифигнутый же?

Comment: @Grundy угу....

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29775797/2881286

Answer (score 1):

Отсылаем `FormData`, в котором будет поле с нужным `json` в виде строки (JSON.stringify)

```
// как пример для отсыла данные
var myData = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
};

var data = new FormData();
data.append("json", JSON.stringify(myData));

fetch("url", {
    method: "POST",
    body: data
}).then(function(response) {
    // Стоит проверить код ответа.
    if (!response.ok) {
        // Сервер вернул код ответа за границами диапазона [200, 299]
        return Promise.reject(new Error(
            'Response failed: ' + response.status + ' (' + response.statusText + ')'
        ));
    }

    // Далее будем использовать только JSON из тела ответа.
    return response.json();
}).then(function(data) {
    // ... Делаем что-то с данными.
}).catch(function(error) {
    // ... Обрабатываем ошибки.
});
```

---

другой вариант банально отдать json в теле:

```
fetch('url', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: 'json=' + JSON.stringify(myData)
})
...
...
```

`json=` - просто, чтоб обозначить ключ на сервере, но можно и без него.

---

подсмотрено на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29823632/6104996) и [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29778812/6104996)

Comment: Дважды кодировать данные - извращение

Comment: @andreymal, где второй раз?

Comment: @Grundy `data.append` — вот тут

Comment: Что значит ключ json во втором варианте? Это хардкод какой-то? Он же в теле запроса не появится?

Comment: @Grundy а после редактирования ответа теперь и `encodeURIComponent` вот тут :)

Comment: @vp_arth появится

Comment: @andreymal думаешь с простым stringify сработет?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а почему нет-то

Comment: @andreymal ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal, например потому, что `&` не заэкранируется, и в теории все может сломаться, если этот символ будет внутри json

Comment: @Grundy всё сломается только в application/x-www-form-urlencoded, в который кодировать как раз и не надо, у нас тут application/json как бы (см. соседний ответ)

Comment: Кстати да, во втором варианте в Content-Type написано application/json, в то время как тело запроса содержит данные в формате application/x-www-form-urlencoded, не надо так делать

Comment: @andreymal что примечательно, в своем [комментарии](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633192/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-json-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-fetch-javascript-%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB/633203?noredirect=1#comment891860_633192) я так и написал......... пока не решил посмотреть   а как там у дядек на enSO ))

Comment: Ох уж эти дядьки)

Comment: @vp_arth да ну их в болото)

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно просто передать `json` в качестве тела запроса:

```js
fetch('http://httpbin.org/post', {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({a: 7, str: 'Строка: &=&'})}).then(res=>res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res));
```