# Fetch, передача параметров в POST запрос

Tags: javascript, fetch

У меня есть POST запрос: 'https://mysterious-reef-29460.herokuapp.com/api/v1/validate'

Чтобы получить ответ, я должен передать такие данные:

```
email: 'max@test.com', password: '12345', content-type: 'application/json'
```

Пробовал сделать так:

```
const status = response => {
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText))
    }
    return Promise.resolve(response)
  }
  const json = response => {
    console.log(response.headers.get('content-type'));
    return response.json()
  }

  fetch('https://mysterious-reef-29460.herokuapp.com/api/v1/validate', {
    method: 'post',
    body: 'test=1',
    headers: {
        'email': 'max@test.com',
        'password': '12345',
    }
  })

    .then(status)
    .then(json)
    .then(data => {
      console.log('data', data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error', error);
    })
```

Но возвращается: `{status: "err", message: "wrong_email_or_password"}`

Comment: Пароль и мыло точно в заголовках передавать надо?

Comment: Потому и спрашиваю, не знаю.

Comment: Так а сервер кто писал? -.- Покажите код валидации серверный.

Comment: С радостью бы вам показал, однако просто есть 'ТЗ', в котором и указан адрес.

Comment: Покажите ТЗ тогда.

Comment: https://vk.com/@maxpfrontend-testovoe-zadanie-2

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [как отправить json на сервер fetch javascript? Все говорят только о том, как получить json](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633192/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-json-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80-fetch-javascript-%d0%92%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Только что `curl`'ом послал запрос:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "content-type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"email\":\"max@test.com\",\"password\":\"12345\"}" http://mysterious-reef-29460.herokuapp.com/api/v1/validate
```

И получил в ответе: `{"status":"ok","data":{"id":1}}`.

Так что, почту и пароль нужно в теле отправлять, а не в заголовках.

```
fetch('https://mysterious-reef-29460.herokuapp.com/api/v1/validate', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify({email: 'max@test.com', password: '12345'}),
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
})
```

Comment: Эх, буквально на минуту опоздал с абсолютно идентичным ответом. Это ж кто писал такое ТЗ, что в нём нет ни одного упоминания о том, как именно нужно отправлять данные к серверу и в каком формате :)

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin там написано, что "POST запросом" и "при нажатии на кнопку", что подразумевает, что данные отправляются в теле POST запроса.