# Как послать ajax запрос методом POST?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

```
<div id="1">
Текст комментария
<span class="like_count">12</span>
<a class="like">мне нравится</a>
</div>
```

Мне нужно что бы по нажатию на ссылку с классом like посылался запрос на страницу site.com/api/like/ с POST параметрами comment_id = 1 (тут id комментария берется из родительского тега div) и like = up_count

При этом необходимо что бы числовое содержимое span тега увеличивалось на 1, то есть было 12 стало 13, но это после того как POST запрос отправлен.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/633235/176064

Answer (score 1):

CLICK надеюсь умеешь на LIKE посадить?
Далее через .closest() находишь родителя DIV, у него получаешь атрибут ID
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Выглядит примерно так (не проверял, могут быть ошибки)

```
$('.like').om('click',function(e){
    var parent = $(e).closest('div');
    $.post( "site.com/api/like/", { comment_id: parent.attr('id')} );
    // ниже код лучше на callback post посадить, но для примера пусть будет так, это проще воспринимать
    var count  = parent.find('like_count');
    count.html( parseInt(count.html() )+1 );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    jQuery('a.r3e').on('click',function () {

var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');

$.ajax({
url:"/api/reviews/uplike/",
method: "POST",
data: ({ id: id }), //отправляем постом id элемента
beforeSend: function(data) {
// выводим диалоговое окно о том что лайк проставляется
alert('ставим лайк');
},

complete: function(data) {
// лайк успешно поставлен, запрос post передан

alert('спасибо за активность на сайте');
}

});


return false;

});
</script>
```

решил вопрос таким способом